# How is Selenium 2.0 different from the previous version, apart from the WebDriver API?

Tags: selenium2, webdriver

I am slowly but surely starting to lean towards selenium 2.0 as everyone is really making a big fuss about it. I would like to know how much different is selenium 2.0 from the previous version apart from the WebDriver API. That is in my opinion about the only difference i have read about or seen.

Would anyone recommend me use Selenium 2.0 from here onward?

Answer (score 3):

Its good news that you are veering towards Selenium 2.0. Please go ahead.  If you want to know more about the difference:

- You can try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5869227/948641) , from good old stack flow where it    appears    to have been discussed earlier.
- In addition, you could try out this [bit](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.html#brief-history-of-the-selenium-project) , wherein the brief history of the Selenium project is discussed. from this you could glean the path followed and the reason for the merger and thus       indirectly some of the differences.
- If you are thirsty for more ,there is an interesting [article](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html)  by Simon Stewart, which can be extremely useful to  know in depth  motivations behind the Selenium2 and its evolution history with       Selenium1 in mind apart from the architecture and roadmap.
- And finally, Google can throw up several other relevant links, apart    from the ones mentioned above if you search with the keywords mentioned in the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to "What is the difference between Selenium IDE, Server, RC, 2.0, and WebDriver?" on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996322/241753) for the full breakdown on the differences between Selenium 1.x and 2.x.  But if you're going to ignore the WebDriver API and stick with the Selenium RC API, the only significant difference is support for newer browser versions.  There have been few bug fixes in the RC API, perhaps even none, depending on which 1.x release you're using.  And there have been no new features for the RC API.